# Canvas coordinates don't work probably after setting up CSS

Tags: css, html, canvas, responsive-design

My drag and drop game in canvas works fine, but after I set in my css-file

```
#canvas
{
    width:100%
}
```

to make my canvas responsive, my coordinates are totally displaced.
For example: If I clicked in the center of an image it doesn't worked. I have to click somewhere near by the image in the offset. Without setting up my css I can click on the image without any problems.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve])?

Comment: In my question it was my minimal example. I only set up the css. But in my canvas tag I also defined the width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `<canvas>` has a size, specified by the `width` and `height` attribute. Those values determine the size of the underlying Image Data Array, too. Additionally those values determine the coordinate system, which is used for the `<canvas>`.

If you scale the `<canvas>` using css, you do not scale the coordinate system of the `<canvas>`. There are too ways to come around that:

1. Scale the `<canvas>` using Javascript and set the `width` and `height` attributes. Note that changing one of them will clear the `<canvas>`
2. Try to figure out the resulting size of the `<canvas>` after the css scaling kicked in and recalculate the mouse coordinates accordingly.

I would recommend to use method 1, since that ensures that the canvas will always appear crisp.

All in all, Libraries like paper.js or similar provide that for you.